# Maxwell's Equations in differential form... what is the advantage?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I once read from a book, "...the derivation of alternative relations between the electric and magnetic fields and their sources that are satisfied at every point in space would have an advantage in solving a wider class of electromagnetic field problems". My question is, if the quintessential problem of electromagnetics is to solve for the electric (or magnetic) field, how does Maxwell's equations in differential form actually offer us an advantage? We still need to integrate to find the fields.

Comment: This very conundrum occurred to me as well. The claim always seems to be that the electromagnetic equations **look elegant** in the formalism of differential forms. But no one says if and how it makes obtaining solutions any easier. Probably it doesn't. Perhaps it may offer a better tool to visualize fields. In Gravitation by MTW this pictorial visualization of forms has been discussed.

Answer (score 5):

What your book is probably getting at is that the integral forms of Maxwell's equations are fairly useless unless you have situations with very high degrees of symmetry and/or fields aligned along co-ordinate axes. e.g. The beloved examples of undergraduate physics everywhere of spherical and cylindrical charge and current distributions.

Once you move away from these situations then the integral forms become extremely difficult to use in practice because they do not apply at a point. If you wish to numerically solve the equations then it is far easier to do that starting off with a set of *differential* equations that are already in the form that are amenable to solving on a "grid".

A second reason to move to the differential forms is to show how electromagnetic waves can exist and can be generated from accelerating charge and current distributions. Whilst I'm sure it is not impossible from the integral forms I doubt it is a sensible approach.

Finally, the differential forms allow you to intuitively grasp some aspects of electromagnetism far more easily. e.g. If I ask you whether the field $\vec{B} = x\vec{i}$  is a valid description for a magnetic field, it is far easier to say that it can't be because the divergence is non-zero than to perform closed surface integrals for (potentially) an infinite number of possible closed surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

At least one benefit can be seen by noticing that combining the differential form of Maxwell's equations allows one to show that even in free space one can have oscillating electric and magnetic fields that satisfy a wave equation. Maybe it'd be possible to demonstrate this using the integral form, however in the differential form everything is much more clear cut and simple.

In general, the differential form allows us to write differential equations for the fields (or equivalently, potentials) very quickly and painlessly, and this allows us to apply the vast body of techniques of differential equations to systems that would otherwise be completely unreasonable to try and integrate.